# IP adresses recognized as phone numbers by Microsoft Edge

Tags: windows-10, skype, microsoft-edge

I have a web page with IP addresses which are text. And Microsoft Edge recognizes some of them as phone numbers. How can I disable this thing from Microsoft Edge?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, this is built in into Edge HTML parsing. There is no setting or plugin that performs this.

Microsoft expects HTML designers to add the following meta in the HTML head section.

```
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
```

Answer (score 0):

#### How can I disable this thing from Microsoft Edge?

This feature is **Skype Click to Call**.

> Skype Click to Call is a really easy way for you to make calls to numbers on websites, with just one click.

---

#### Removing Skype Click to Call

> You can go to your Control Panel to uninstall Skype Click to Call:
>
> For Windows XP:
>
> - Click Start > Control Panel > Add or Remove Programs.
> - Find Skype Click to Call and click Remove.
>
> For Windows Vista and 7:
>
> - Click Start > Control Panel > Programs and Features > Uninstall a Program.
> - Find Skype Click to Call and click Uninstall.
>
> For Windows 8/8.1:
>
> - Move your mouse to the top right hand corner of the screen, and click the Search option.
> - In the search box, type Add or remove programs, then click on the Add or remove programs search suggestion that comes up.
> - Find Skype Click to Call and click Uninstall.

Source [How do I use Skype Click to Call?](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA657/how-do-i-use-skype-click-to-call)

Comment: Sadly I have no "Skype Click to Call". I only have "Skype™ 7.3" and "Get Skype".

Comment: I have uninstalled both "Skype™ 7.3" and "Get Skype". Microsoft Edge still highlights some of the IP addresses and asks me to download app from the store.